# Mathematica not able to confirm its own solution to differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I type the following into *Mathematica*:

```
DSolve[q''[x] + 2 x/(x^2 - 1) q'[x] - 4*q[x]/(x^2 - 1) == 0, q[x], x]
```

It gives me the result

```
q[x] -> C[1] LegendreP[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[17]), x] + 
  C[2] LegendreQ[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[17]), x]
```

Suppose I take `C[2]=0` and `C[1] =1`, and then I try the following command:

```
FullSimplify[
 D[D[LegendreP[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[17]), x], x], x] + 
  2*x/(x^2 - 1)*D[LegendreP[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[17]), x], x] - 
  4*LegendreP[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[17]), x]/(x^2 - 1)]
```

This is evaluating the LHS of the diff eq at the solution, as provided by *Mathematica*, and yet the result I get is NOT zero:

I get

```
(1/(2 (-1 + 
   x^2)^2))((9 + Sqrt[17]) LegendreP[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[17]), 
    x] - (19 + 3 Sqrt[17]) x LegendreP[1/2 (1 + Sqrt[17]), x] + 
  2 (5 + Sqrt[17]) LegendreP[1/2 (3 + Sqrt[17]), x])
```

I was wondering if someone knew how I could make it fully simplify the result to give me zero, as numerically evaluating it gives extremely small numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the other answers have mentioned, you can confirm the solution without specifying values for `C[1]` and `C[2]`

```
lhs = q''[x] + 2 x/(x^2 - 1) q'[x] - 4*q[x]/(x^2 - 1);
sol = DSolve[lhs == 0, q, x][[1, 1]]; 
FullSimplify[lhs /. sol]
```

> 0

When `C[2]` is set to zero, `FullSimplify` is unable to find the right transformations to reduce the expression to zero, and the simplest form it can find is, as noted in the question:

```
result = FullSimplify[lhs /. sol /. {C[1] -> 1, C[2] -> 0}]
```

> $\frac{1}{2 \left(-1+x^2\right)^2}\left(\left(9+\sqrt{17}\right) \text{LegendreP}\left[\frac{1}{2} \left(-1+\sqrt{17}\right),x\right]-\left(19+3 \sqrt{17}\right) x \text{LegendreP}\left[\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{17}\right),x\right]+2 \left(5+\sqrt{17}\right) \text{LegendreP}\left[\frac{1}{2} \left(3+\sqrt{17}\right),x\right]\right)$

This result **is** zero, which can be confirmed by evaluating for numerical values of $x$. Be aware though, that using machine precision may lead to numerical errors:

```
result /. x -> 0.1
```

> 1.81242*10^-15

A good idea when you see unexpected results like this is to make *Mathematica* use arbitrary-precision by specifying the precision of the number:

```
result /. x -> 0.1`20
```

> 0.*10^-18

Comment: thanks, it worked. I would have thought it was easier for mathematica to simplify something for one particular value of parameter, rather than doing it for all possible values!, but I guess not.

Answer (score 2):

On the other hand, we can use `DifferentialRootReduce[]` on `LegendreP[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[17]), x]` to see what linear differential equation is satisfied by it:

```
Operate[FullSimplify, DifferentialRootReduce[LegendreP[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[17]), x], x]]
   DifferentialRoot[Function[{y, x}, {-4 y[x] + 2 x y'[x] + (-1 + x^2) y''[x] == 0,
                    y[0] == Sqrt[π]/(Gamma[3/4 - Sqrt[17]/4] Gamma[(3 + Sqrt[17])/4]),
                    y'[0] == -((1 + Sqrt[17]) Sqrt[π])/
                    (2 Gamma[1/4 - Sqrt[17]/4] Gamma[(5 + Sqrt[17])/4])}]][x]
```

where all the formal symbols were replaced with their normal equivalents for clarity. (Note the use of `Operate[]` so that `FullSimplify[]` is applied only to the `DifferentialRoot[]` object.) In any case, the ODE thus produced (the first element in the list within the `Function[]`) can then be seen to be the same as the one in the OP.

---

Apparently, the reason why *Mathematica* could not recognize the complicated expression in Simon's answer as $0$ is due to its inability to see that one can use the [recurrence relation for the Legendre functions](http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LegendreP/17/01/01/0002/) in this case.

```
expr = FullSimplify[q''[x] + 2 x/(x^2 - 1) q'[x] - 4*q[x]/(x^2 - 1) /. 
                    q -> Function[x, LegendreP[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[17]), x]]];

FullSimplify[expr /. Activate[Function[{n, z}, Inactivate[LegendreP[n, z] ==
             (((2 n - 1) z) LegendreP[n - 1, z] -
             (n - 1) LegendreP[n - 2, z])/n]][(3 + Sqrt[17])/2, x] /. Equal -> Rule]]
   0
```

where I took the required form of the recurrence from the results of `MathematicalFunctionData[LegendreP, "DifferenceEquations"]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do :

```
sol[x_] = q[x] /. 
 First@DSolve[q''[x] + 2 x/(x^2 - 1) q'[x] - 4*q[x]/(x^2 - 1) == 0, q[x], x]

FullSimplify[Derivative[2][sol][x] + 2 x/(x^2 - 1) Derivative[1][sol][x] - 
  4*sol[x]/(x^2 - 1)]
(* 0 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you may not chose one parameter to 0. E.g. try `c2=2` and `c1=1`:

```
FullSimplify[
D[LegendreP[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[17]), x] + 
2 LegendreQ[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[17]), x], {x, 2}] + 
2*x/(x^2 - 1)*
D[LegendreP[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[17]), x] + 
 2 LegendreQ[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[17]), x], x] - 
4*(LegendreP[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[17]), x] + 
  2 LegendreQ[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[17]), x])/(x^2 - 1)]
```

As output you will get 0. But I admit that this is really odd. Actually I agree with you and would say that you may set one of your constants to 0. Also, if I replace one of the constants with non-integers, I get back values which are only almost 0.

But if you try

```
 DSolve[D[q[x], {x, 2}] + 2 x/(x^2 - 1) *D[q[x], x] -  4*q[x]/(x^2 - 1) == 0, q, x]

 FullSimplify[D[q[x], {x, 2}] + 2 x/(x^2 - 1)*D[q[x], x] - 4*q[x]/(x^2 - 1) /. %]
```

your result is confirmed. So, I guess if you work with real numbers, you get numerical problems.